# Android LightWeightChart: Change Half of the chart color grey while Moving on chart with right to left :

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, tradingview-api

I'm using the `'com.tradingview:lightweightcharts:4.0.0'` library for charting in android kotlin.
I want to implement a feature where when a user interacts with the chart by clicking or holding, the right side of the chart changes color to gray or becomes partially transparent.

[What I want to achieve : image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjP2L.png)

[LightWeightChart](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/tutorials/customization/intro)

this is method where I am detecting the moving points.

```
private var curSeries: SeriesApi? = null    
chartsVAPI.subscribeCrosshairMove { param -> }

 private fun setChartData(a: List<LineData>) {
     
        curSeries?.setData(a)
        chartsVAPI.timeScale.fitContent()
    }




chartsVAPI.addAreaSeries(
            options = areaSeriesOptions {
                priceScaleId = PriceScaleId.RIGHT
                lineColor = IntColor(resources.getColor(R.color.line_upper, theme))
                topColor = IntColor(resources.getColor(R.color.red_upper, theme))
                bottomColor = IntColor(resources.getColor(R.color.red, theme))
                priceLineVisible = false
                title = "2%"

            },
            onSeriesCreated = { series ->
                curSeries = series
                setChartData(listCustomPrice)

            }
        )
```

I have also tried [plugins](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/tutorials/customization/intro) but not sure how to use it.